# Add javascript pixel values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way in javascript/jQuery to take two variables with values "60px" and "40px" and add them together to get "100px"?

Or in a more general sense, I'm trying to calculate positions of objects relative to other objects and it would be really convenient if I could do something like this:

```
$('#object2').css('left', $('#object1').css('left')+'60px');
```

Of course, that just gives in invalid "40px60px".

Comment: For JS Devs those who landed on this page searching for this - Beware you are reaching new heights of procrastination !

Answer (score 26, accepted):

remove px from strings, add values, then add px back

```
  (parseInt("40px".replace(/px/,""))+60)+"px"
```

Comment: That gives me "4060px" in the chrome console log. However using parseInt as suggested by other answers I get "100px" from this modification: `(parseInt("40px".replace(/px/,""))+60)+"px"`

Comment: Right, my mistake, should put the number in front, otherwise it adds strings. parseInt makes number out of string, so should work well too.

Answer (score 11):

You're looking for the [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function.

```
var left1 = "40px";
var left2 = "60px";

// Add the integer values of the left values together
var leftTotal = parseInt( left1, 10 ) + parseInt( left2, 10 ) + "px";
```

Also worth investigating is the [parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) method. It does the same thing as parseInt(), but works on numbers with decimals (aka floating point values).

Answer (score 7):

Probably the most efficient way is

```
parseInt("40px", 10) + parseInt("60px", 10) + "px"
```

The `10`'s in the parseInt calls are necessary to protect against the value being mistakenly calculated in something other than base 10.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on Chrome, I seem to get a NaN until the 'px' component is removed

Comment: I think this is better answer, as **1:** question was:  _two **variables** with values "60px" and "40px"_, and in accepted answer the second value is not a variable, **2:** `parseInt` will convert '40px' to 40, so there is no need for `replace(/px/,"")`. Adding `+ "px"` should convert Integer to String, same way as it's doing it in the accepted answer. This solution is working as it should, so can someone explain why would @wheresrhys be getting NaN?

Answer (score 2):

```
var shiftedRight = (parseFloat($('#object1').css('left')) + 60) + 'px';
$('#object2').css('left', shiftedRight);
```

`parseFloat` will parse only the prefix of the string that is a number.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by parsing the css.left value of the object, somewhat like this:

```
$('#object2').css('left', (parseInt($('#object1').css('left')) + 60) + 'px');
```

But you should keep in mind, that the css.left value might not be `px` but also `%`, `em`, etc. so the clean way would be using [jQuery offset method](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) as that would give you the correct pixels value.

```
$('#object2').css('left', ($('#object1').offset().left + 60) + 'px');
```

Answer (score 0):

It won't work in Firefox yet but you could use Typed OM for this.

To set one HTML elements `left` to be the value of another elements `left` + 60px:

```js
const object1 = document.getElementById('object1');
const object2 = document.getElementById('object2');

object2.attributeStyleMap.set('left', CSS.px(object1.computedStyleMap().get('left').value + 60));
```