# Applying a variable to an element's style property with js

Tags: javascript, html

Sorry if this question has already been asked.  If so, could someone please direct me to the thread(s)?  I have not found any existing ones so far.

But my question revolves around this type of action:

```
    var Product_Linky = document.getElementById("Product_Link_Container");
    Product_Linky.style.position.left= 12px;
```

A literal is being applied to the attribute with the indicated units.  But...can a variable be applied and if so, how would the units be specified?

The following code is not written properly, but it shows an example of the problem I have:

```
    var Product_Linky = document.getElementById("Product_Link_Container");
    Product_Linky.style.position.left= 'MyVariable_x'px ;
```

If a variable can be used, what is the correct syntax to include the units?

Best regards!

Comment: Search stackoverflow for string concatenation in javascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add javascript pixel values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333036/add-javascript-pixel-values)

Comment: Are you sure of the code in general? You can specify `style.left = "12px"` or `style.position = "absolute"`, for instance. What does `style.position.left` mean?

Comment: Thanks, guys!  As soon as you mentioned concantination, I thought, "DoH!".

Comment: "Are you sure of the code in general?"...No...But what I was referring to is that I was going after the style's position "property", and specifically, the left attribute of that property (not the others, right, top, bottom).  I hope I have the terminology correct, here.  But I see your point.  Still can't get it to work.  UPDATE:  It DOES work.  Thanks for the great help everyone!

Answer (score 1):

There's a similar question already, but to answer your question this will work:

```
var variable_Length = 5;
var Product_Linky = document.getElementById("Product_Link_Container");
Product_Linky.style.position.left= variable_Length + 'px' ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this, my friend. It's called ES6 template literal

```
Product_Linky.style.position.left= `${MyVariable_x}px` ;
```

Or you do the String concatenation like this

```
Product_Linky.style.position.left= MyVariable_x + 'px' ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using template Literals!
In JavaScript, if you want to make a variable "fit in" to a string, you an use the following syntax:

```
var num = 12;
var myString = `My number is ${num}.`;
console.log(myString);
```

will log

```
My number is 12.
```

One important note on this: you **cannot** use regular quotation marks to enclose the string. You **must** use the backtick:

```
`
```

(it should be right above your tab key). Otherwise, this will not work.

For more information, check out the [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)!

For an example, check out [this Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oPYKWE) I made! (Try changing the `myHeight` variable's value.)

I hope that helps!