# Why does this setinterval work only once?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, setinterval

Ok so, on my website I have three long panorama images on top of each other. I want them all to scoot 100px to the left every second. Here's what I tried:

```
var panoramas = document.getElementsByClassName("pano");

setInterval(scoot, 1000);

function scoot(){ 
    for (i=0; i < panoramas.length; i++){ 
        panoramas[i].style.left = panoramas[i].style.left - 100; 
    }
}
```

But what happens is that they scoot 100px to the left once, and stop. I tried some console.logs in there so I know it's looping, but they won't move more than once.

Comment: are you handling the units?

Comment: `panoramas[i].style.left` does not read styles from CSS files. It returns a string with unit and expects a string with unit. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: doh lol my bad-- deleted

Comment: You can't subtract `100` from`"250px"` (or whatever it is initially) because of the units.  And you can't subtract `100` from  an empty string (if there is no local style set yet).  Probably the first of these if biting you (units), so read [Add javascript pixel values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333036/add-javascript-pixel-values)

Answer (score 0):

`panoramas[i].style.left` does not read styles from CSS files. It returns a string with unit and expects a string with unit.

```js
var panoramas = document.getElementsByClassName("pano");

setInterval(scoot, 1000);

function scoot() {
  for (i = 0; i < panoramas.length; i++) {
    panoramas[i].style.left = panoramas[i].style.left.replace(/\d+/, p1 => +p1 - 100);
  }
}
```

```css
.pano {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="pano" style="left: 200px; top: 50px;"></div>
<div class="pano" style="left: 250px; top: 100px;"></div>
<div class="pano" style="left: 300px; top= 150px;"></div>
```

Comment: Where did you get the idea the OP was expecting a value from CSS?

Comment: @pilchard It's only a hint.

Comment: But kind of random, also straight string manipulation is probably more efficient than regex (and you're assuming an initial inline style so it fails if there isn't one).

Comment: @pilchard I didn't know `parseInt` can handle strings containing numbers and other characters. The accepted and most upovoted answer uses a regex. All the answers in the duplicate consider only `px`. Why do you assume only this unit? My answer can handle more cases than the answers in the duplicate.

Comment: @pilchard I assume an online style, because `panoramas[i].style.left`. Why should I assume something different?