# Loop through and add pixels values javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to know how we can loop through and add pixel values?

Example,

```
let testArray = [{width: '150px'}, {width : '150px'}]
```

So i want to loop through it and have to return total value i.e '**300px**'

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Basically i need to calculate 150px + 150 px = 300 px, but i want to loop through it using map as width values may increase

Comment: You can't have the same key twice in an object

Comment: There is nothing really to loop or map since it is an array with exactly one object. Also, that object can't have a property with the same name 2 or more times. Can you explain better what is your use case?

Comment: @Marios updated the array of objects, so i want to loop through array of objects of width key and have to do addition

Comment: @adiga updated the array of obejcts

Comment: Duplicate of [Add javascript pixel values?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9333130)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 let sumWidth = 0
    testArray.forEach((object)=>{
    sumWidth+= parseInt(object.width.slice(0,-2))
    }

let result = sumWidth.toString() + 'px'
```